# NSToolbar in NSWindow not displaying properly

Tags: xcode, macos, nswindow, nstoolbar

I'm writing this MacOS application which has a toolbar like this one:
[image]

Everything was working fine, but at some point it is only displaying the following:

[image]

I've tried everything [here](https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Fixing-Xcode) with no luck. Even deleted the whole Toolbar, but it still appears when I build the application, and can't get rid of it. 
I'm using Xcode 9, MacOS X High Sierra, and this is how my NSWindow tree looks like before deleting the Toolbar:

[image]

Any clues?

Comment: Is the toolbar different at some point in your app or was it working fine, you changed something and now the toolbar is differrent. Is the view controller a `NSTabViewController`?

Comment: Sorry I don't really get you... The controller is a Window Controller. The window has a toolbar which is not drawing correctly, but it was before. Only after some builds I've realized that something happened to it. It's so broken, that even if I delete the toolbar at the Interface Builder, the toolbar is still being drawn as I show on the second picture.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure not to have a Tab View Controller in the same window whose style is set to "Toolbar"

[image]

Accidentally I set this parameter at some point while configuring the interface.I didn't
realized that what I was seeing at my toolbar was a tabViewController and not a Segmented Control Thanks to user Willeke for pointing that out